# AttributeError: 'IAPWS97' object has no attribute 'rho'

Tags: attributes

I am trying to run this loop; however, I am getting a no attribute error in the second portion of my code. Below is the entire code (sorry for the length). When I run the first case (PWR) the code executes normally as expected. However, when I run the second case (BWR) I receive the error even though it is the same exact statement from case one. Is there any fix or explanation for this? Thank you.

```
import numpy as np
import math
from iapws import IAPWS97
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

case = int(input('Which case [1 (PWR) or 2 (BWR)]? '))

if case == 1:  # PWR
    H = 3.8  # m
    He = 3.8  # m
    Pitch = 1.25 * 10 ** (-2)  # m
    Gap_t = 0.00006  # m
    D_fuel = 0.0082  # m
    k_gap = 0.25  # W/m-K
    k_c = 21.5  # W/m-K
    k_fuel = 3.6  # W/m-K
    T0 = float(278 + 273.15)  # K
    q0_prime = float(330 * 10 ** (2))  # W/m
    P0 = 15  # MPa
    MF = float(3460)  # kg/m^2-s
    D_rod = .0095  # m
    R_rod = D_rod / 2
    R_fuel = D_fuel / 2
    R_gap = R_fuel + Gap_t
    R_clad = R_rod
    Clad_t = D_rod - D_fuel - Gap_t  # m
    h0_enthalpy = (IAPWS97(T=T0, P=P0).h) * 10 ** (3)
    T_sat0 = IAPWS97(P=P0, x=0).T
    g = 9.81  # m/s

    # geometry properties
    heated_p = math.pi * D_rod
    wetted_p = math.pi * D_rod
    A_f = (Pitch ** 2) - ((1 / 4) * math.pi * (D_rod ** 2))
    D_H = (4 * A_f) / heated_p

    # grid setup
    grid_points = 100
    dz = H / grid_points
    z_array = np.arange(0, H, dz)
    z_arrayplots = np.arange(0, H, dz)
    q_HeatFluxList = []

    # defining array of q'' values in list
    for z in z_array:
        heat_fluxA = (q0_prime / (math.pi * D_rod)) * math.sin(math.pi * (z / He))
        q_HeatFluxList.append(heat_fluxA)

    q_heat_flux = np.array(q_HeatFluxList)

    q_prime = np.zeros(len(z_array))

    for i in range(0, len(z_array)):
        q_prime[i] = q0_prime * math.sin((np.pi * z_array[i]) / He)

    # defining array of h values
    h_enthalpy_list = []
    h_enthalpy_prefactor = ((heated_p * q0_prime * H) / (A_f * MF * (math.pi ** 2) * D_rod))
    for z in z_array:
        h_enthalpy = (-h_enthalpy_prefactor * math.cos(math.pi * (z / He))) + h_enthalpy_prefactor + h0_enthalpy
        h_enthalpy_list.append(h_enthalpy)

    h_enthalpy_array_J = np.array(h_enthalpy_list)
    h_enthalpy_array = h_enthalpy_array_J * 10 ** (-3)

    P_array = np.zeros(len(z_array))
    P_array[0] = P0

    T_sat = np.zeros(len(z_array))
    T_sat[0] = T_sat0

    T_f_array = np.zeros(len(z_array))
    T_f_array[0] = T0

    Re = np.zeros(len(z_array))
    Re_f = np.zeros(len(z_array))
    Pr = np.zeros(len(z_array))

    k_fluid = np.zeros(len(z_array))

    x_array = np.zeros(len(z_array))
    xe_array = np.zeros(len(z_array))

    frictional = np.zeros(len(z_array))
    gravitational = np.zeros(len(z_array))
    compressibility = np.zeros(len(z_array))

    # Pressure Loop PWR
    dp = 0.001
    for i in range(0, len(z_array) - 1):
        rho_f = IAPWS97(P=P_array[i], x=0).rho
        vf = IAPWS97(P=P_array[i], x=0).v
        vg = IAPWS97(P=P_array[i], x=1).v
        hf_enthalpy = IAPWS97(P=P_array[i], x=0).h
        hg_enthalpy = IAPWS97(P=P_array[i], x=1).h
        muf = (IAPWS97(P=P_array[i], x=0).mu) * 10 ** (-6)
        mug = (IAPWS97(P=P_array[i], x=1).mu) * 10 ** (-6)
        k_fluid[i] = IAPWS97(P=P_array[i], T=T_f_array[i]).k
        Pr[i] = IAPWS97(P=P_array[i], h=h_enthalpy_array[i]).Liquid.Prandt

        x_array[i] = 0
        xe_array[i] = (h_enthalpy_array[i] - hf_enthalpy) / (hg_enthalpy - hf_enthalpy)

        rho_m = 1 / ((x_array[i] * vg) + ((1 - x_array[i]) * vf))
        mu_m = 1 / ((x_array[i] / mug) + ((1 - x_array[i]) / muf))

        Re[i] = (MF * D_H) / (mu_m * 10 ** 6)  # convert mu to Pa/s
        f = 0.079 * (Re[i] ** -0.25) * (mu_m / muf)
        Tau = (1 / 2) * f * ((MF ** 2) / rho_m)

        Re_f[i] = Re[i]

        vf_plus_dP = IAPWS97(P=P_array[i] + dp, x=0).v
        vf_minus_dP = IAPWS97(P=P_array[i] - dp, x=0).v

        ddP_vf = (vf_plus_dP - vf_minus_dP) / (2 * (dp * 10 ** 6))

        frictional[i] = (Tau * wetted_p) / A_f
        gravitational[i] = g * rho_f
        compressibility[i] = (MF ** 2) * (ddP_vf)

        dPdz_num = (frictional[i] + gravitational[i])  # Pa/m
        dPdz_denom = 1 + compressibility[i]  # Pa/m
        dPdz = -dPdz_num / dPdz_denom  # Pa/m

        P_array[i + 1] = P_array[i] + ((dPdz * dz) * 10 ** (-6))
        T_f_array[i + 1] = IAPWS97(P=P_array[i + 1], h=h_enthalpy_array[i + 1]).T
        T_sat[i + 1] = IAPWS97(P=P_array[i + 1], x=0).T

    # final calc for final value of quality and void fraction because loop stops before these
    hf_final = IAPWS97(P=P_array[-1], x=0).h
    hg_final = IAPWS97(P=P_array[-1], x=1).h
    muf_final = (IAPWS97(P=P_array[-1], x=0).mu) * 10 ** (-6)
    mug_final = (IAPWS97(P=P_array[-1], x=1).mu) * 10 ** (-6)
    k_fluid[-1] = IAPWS97(P=P_array[-1], T=T_f_array[-1]).k

    xe_array[-1] = (h_enthalpy_array[-1] - hf_final) / (hg_final - hf_final)

    # fuel and clad temps
    T_C_Outer = np.zeros(len(z_array))

    mu_m_final = 1 / ((x_array[-1] / mug_final) + ((1 - x_array[-1]) / muf_final))

    Re_f[-1] = (MF * D_H) / (muf_final * 10 ** 6)

    Pr[-1] = IAPWS97(P=P_array[i], h=h_enthalpy_array[i]).Liquid.Prandt

    h_HT = 0.023 * (Re_f[0] ** 0.8) * (Pr[0] ** 0.4) * (k_fluid[0] / D_H)

    T_C_Outer[0] = (q_heat_flux[0] + (h_HT * T_f_array[0])) / h_HT

    for i in range(0, len(z_array) - 1):
        h_HT = 0.023 * (Re_f[i + 1] ** 0.8) * (Pr[i + 1] ** 0.4) * (k_fluid[i + 1] / D_H)
        T_C_Outer[i + 1] = (q_heat_flux[i + 1] + (h_HT * T_f_array[i + 1])) / h_HT

    q_triple_prime = (q_prime * 4) / (np.pi * (D_fuel ** 2))

    T_C_Inner = np.zeros(len(z_array))
    T_F_Outer = np.zeros(len(z_array))
    T_F_Center = np.zeros(len(z_array))

    for i in range(0, len(z_array)):
        C1 = -((q0_prime * R_clad) / (k_c * heated_p)) * np.sin(np.pi * (z_array[i] / H))
        C2 = T_C_Outer[i] - (C1 * np.log(R_clad))

        T_C_Inner[i] = (C1 * np.log(R_gap)) + C2

        C3 = (k_c / k_gap) * C1
        C4 = T_C_Inner[i] - (C3 * np.log(R_gap))

        T_F_Outer[i] = (C3 * np.log(R_fuel)) + C4

        C6 = T_F_Outer[i] + ((q_triple_prime[i] * (R_fuel ** 2)) / (4 * k_fuel))

        T_F_Center[i] = C6

    CL_max = np.amax(T_F_Center)
    index = np.where(T_F_Center == CL_max)
    z_CL_max = z_array[index]
    Clad_max = np.amax(T_C_Inner)
    index = np.where(T_C_Inner == Clad_max)
    z_Clad_max = z_array[index]

    plt.figure(1)
    plt.plot(T_C_Outer, z_arrayplots, label='Clad Outer Surface Temp')
    plt.plot(T_C_Inner, z_arrayplots, label='Clad Inner Surface Temp')
    plt.legend(loc='upper left')
    plt.xlabel("Temperature [K]")
    plt.ylabel("Height z [m]")
    plt.savefig("TempClad.png", dpi=600)

    plt.figure(2)
    plt.plot(T_C_Outer, z_arrayplots, label='Clad Outer Surface Temp')
    plt.plot(T_C_Inner, z_arrayplots, label='Clad Inner Surface Temp')
    plt.plot(T_F_Outer, z_arrayplots, label='Fuel Outer Surface Temp')
    plt.plot(T_F_Center, z_arrayplots, label='Fuel Centerline Temp')
    plt.legend(loc='upper left')
    plt.xlabel("Temperature [K]")
    plt.ylabel("Height z [m]")
    plt.savefig("TempFuelAndClad.png", dpi=600)

    # radial calcs
    T_array_A = [T_F_Center[25], T_F_Outer[25], T_C_Inner[25], T_C_Outer[25]]
    T_array_B = [T_F_Center[49], T_F_Outer[49], T_C_Inner[49], T_C_Outer[49]]
    T_array_C = [T_F_Center[53], T_F_Outer[53], T_C_Inner[53], T_C_Outer[53]]
    r_array = [0, R_fuel, R_gap, R_clad]

    plt.figure(3)
    plt.plot(r_array, T_array_A, label='z = -H/4 = -0.9 m')
    plt.plot(r_array, T_array_B, label='z = 0 m')
    plt.plot(r_array, T_array_C, '--', label='z = zmax = 0.108 m')
    plt.legend(loc='upper left')
    plt.ylabel("Temperature [K]")
    plt.xlabel("Radius r [m]")
    plt.savefig("TempRadial.png", dpi=600)

    # critical heat flux and DNBR

    P_array_DNBR = np.delete(P_array, 0)
    q_heat_flux_DNBR = np.delete(q_heat_flux, 0)
    z_arrayplots_DNBR = np.delete(z_arrayplots, 0)

    G_Mlbs = MF * (((2.20462 * 10 ** (-6)) * 3600) / 10.7639)

    q_heat_flux_MBtu = q_heat_flux[1:] * 3.41 * (1 / 1000000) * (1 / 10.7639)

    P_c = 22.064  # https://nuclearstreet.com/nuclear-power-plants/w/nuclear_power_plants/features-of-pressurized-water-reactors
    P_crit = P_array_DNBR / P_c
    P1 = 0.5328
    P2 = 0.1212
    P3 = 1.6151
    P4 = 1.4066
    P5 = -0.3040
    P6 = 0.4843
    P7 = -0.3285
    P8 = -2.0749

    A = P1 * (P_crit ** P2) * (G_Mlbs ** (P5 + (P7 * P_crit)))
    C = P3 * (P_crit ** P4) * (G_Mlbs ** (P6 + (P8 * P_crit)))

    q_crit_heat_flux_MBtu = (A - xe_array[0]) / (C + ((xe_array[1:] - xe_array[0]) / q_heat_flux_MBtu))

    q_crit_heat_flux = q_crit_heat_flux_MBtu * (1 / 3.41) * 1000000 * 10.7639

    DNBR = q_crit_heat_flux / q_heat_flux_DNBR

    plt.figure(4)
    plt.plot(DNBR, z_arrayplots_DNBR)
    plt.xlabel("Departure from Nucleate Boiling Ratio")
    plt.ylabel("Height z [m]")
    plt.savefig("DNBR.png", dpi=600)

    plt.figure(5)
    plt.plot(P_array, z_arrayplots)
    plt.xlabel('Pressure [MPa]')
    plt.ylabel('Height z [m]')
    plt.savefig("Pressure.png", dpi=600)

    plt.figure(6)
    plt.plot(T_f_array, z_arrayplots)
    plt.xlabel('Temperature [K]')
    plt.ylabel('Height z [m]')
    plt.savefig("TempBulk.png", dpi=600)

    plt.figure(7)
    plt.plot(T_F_Outer, z_arrayplots, label='Fuel Outer Surface Temp')
    plt.plot(T_F_Center, z_arrayplots, label='Fuel Centerline Temp')
    plt.legend(loc='upper left')
    plt.xlabel("Temperature [K]")
    plt.ylabel("Height z [m]")
    plt.savefig("TempFuel.png", dpi=600)

    tempdifference = T_C_Outer - T_f_array
    print("Max clad vs bulk difference is " + str(np.amax(tempdifference)) + " K")
    print("Max coolant temp is " + str(np.amax(T_f_array)) + " K")
    print("Min coolant temp is " + str(np.amin(T_f_array)) + " K")
    print("Max clad inner temp is " + str(np.amax(T_C_Inner)) + " K")
    print("Max clad outer temp is " + str(np.amax(T_C_Outer)) + " K")
    print("min clad outer temp is " + str(np.amin(T_C_Outer)) + " K")
    print("Max fuel temp is " + str(np.amax(T_F_Center)) + " K")
    print("Max fuel outer temp is " + str(np.amax(T_F_Outer)) + " K")
    print("Min fuel outer temp is " + str(np.amin(T_F_Outer)) + " K")
    print("Max centerline temp occurs at z = " + str(z_CL_max) + "m")
    print("Max clad temp occurs at z = " + str(z_Clad_max) + "m")
    MDNBR = np.amin(DNBR)
    print("MDNBR is " + str(MDNBR))

    plt.show()

if case == 2:  # BWR
    H = 3.8  # m
    He = 3.8  # m
    Pitch = 1.63 * 10 ** (-2)  # m
    Gap_t = 0.0001  # m
    D_fuel = 0.0104  # m
    k_gap = 0.25  # W/m-K
    k_c = 21.5  # W/m-K
    k_fuel = 3.6  # W/m-K
    T0 = float(274 + 273.15)  # K
    q0_prime = float(410 * 10 ** (2))  # W/m
    P0 = 7.5  # MPa
    MF = float(2290)  # kg/m^2-s
    D_rod = .0123  # m
    R_rod = D_rod / 2
    R_fuel = D_fuel / 2
    R_gap = R_fuel + Gap_t
    R_clad = R_rod
    Clad_t = D_rod - D_fuel - Gap_t  # m
    h0_enthalpy = (IAPWS97(T=T0, P=P0).h) * 10 ** (3)
    T_sat0 = IAPWS97(P=P0, x=0).T
    g = 9.81  # m/s

    # geometry properties
    heated_p = math.pi * D_rod
    wetted_p = math.pi * D_rod
    A_f = (Pitch ** 2) - ((1 / 4) * math.pi * (D_rod ** 2))
    D_H = (4 * A_f) / heated_p

    # grid setup
    grid_points = 100
    dz = H / grid_points
    z_array = np.arange(0, H, dz)
    z_arrayplots = np.arange(-H / 2, H / 2, dz)
    q_HeatFluxList = []

    # defining array of q'' values in list
    for z in z_array:
        heat_fluxA = (q0_prime / (math.pi * D_rod)) * math.sin(math.pi * (z / He))
        q_HeatFluxList.append(heat_fluxA)

    q_heat_flux = np.array(q_HeatFluxList)

    q_prime = np.zeros(len(z_array))

    for i in range(0, len(z_array)):
        q_prime[i] = q0_prime * math.sin((np.pi * z_array[i]) / He)

    # defining array of h values
    h_enthalpy_list = []
    h_enthalpy_prefactor = ((heated_p * q0_prime * H) / (A_f * MF * (math.pi ** 2) * D_rod))
    for z in z_array:
        h_enthalpy = (-h_enthalpy_prefactor * math.cos(math.pi * (z / He))) + h_enthalpy_prefactor + h0_enthalpy
        h_enthalpy_list.append(h_enthalpy)

    h_enthalpy_array_J = np.array(h_enthalpy_list)
    h_enthalpy_array = h_enthalpy_array_J * 10 ** (-3)

    P_array = np.zeros(len(z_array))
    P_array[0] = P0

    T_sat = np.zeros(len(z_array))
    T_sat[0] = T_sat0

    T_f_array = np.zeros(len(z_array))
    T_f_array[0] = T0

    Re = np.zeros(len(z_array))
    Re_f = np.zeros(len(z_array))
    Pr = np.zeros(len(z_array))

    k_fluid = np.zeros(len(z_array))

    x_array = np.zeros(len(z_array))
    xe_array = np.zeros(len(z_array))
    dxe_array = np.zeros(len(z_array))

    frictional = np.zeros(len(z_array))
    gravitational = np.zeros(len(z_array))
    compressibility = np.zeros(len(z_array))

    alpha_array = np.zeros(len(z_array))

    # Pressure Loop BWR
    dp = 0.001
    for i in range(0, len(z_array) - 1):
        rho_f = IAPWS97(P=P_array[i], x=0).rho
        rho_m = IAPWS97(P=P_array[i], x=xe_array[i]).rho
        vf = IAPWS97(P=P_array[i], x=0).v
        vg = IAPWS97(P=P_array[i], x=1).v
        vfg = vg - vf
        hf_enthalpy = IAPWS97(P=P_array[i], x=0).h
        hg_enthalpy = IAPWS97(P=P_array[i], x=1).h
        hfg = hg_enthalpy - hf_enthalpy
        hfg_sat = IAPWS97(P=P0, x=1).h - IAPWS97(P=P0, x=0).h
        # vf = IAPWS97(P=P_array[i], x=0).v
        # vg_sat = IAPWS97(P=P_array[i], x=1).v
        hf_in = IAPWS97(P=P0, T=T0).h
        muf = (IAPWS97(P=P_array[i], x=0).mu) * 10 ** (-6)
        mum = (IAPWS97(P=P_array[i], x=xe_array[i]).mu) * 10 ** (-6)
        mug = (IAPWS97(P=P_array[i], x=1).mu) * 10 ** (-6)
        k_fluid[i] = IAPWS97(P=P_array[i], T=T_f_array[i]).k
        Pr[i] = IAPWS97(P=P_array[i], h=h_enthalpy_array[i]).Liquid.Prandt
        xe_in = (hf_in - hf_enthalpy) / (hfg)
        vf_sat = IAPWS97(P=P_array[i], x=xe_array[i])

    # vapor quality

    if xe_array[i] <= 0:  # single phase
        Re1p = MF * D_rod / muf
        f1p = 0.316 * Re1p ** (-.25)
        dp = -(.5 * f1p * MF * 2 * heated_p / (rho_f * A_f) + g / rho_f) * dz

        x_array[i] = 0
        dxe_array[i] = q0_prime * np.sin(np.pi * z_array[i] / H) / (MF * A_f * hfg_sat) * dz
        xe_array = xe_array[i - 1] + dxe_array[i]
        # P_array[i]=P[i-1]+dp1p

    elif xe_array[i] > 0 and xe_array[i] < 1:  # 2 phase
        Re2p = MF * D_rod / mum
        f2p = 0.046 * Re2p ** (-.2) * (muf / mum ** (-.2))
        dp2p = (-MF ** 2 * vfg * dxe_array[i] + .5 * f2p * MF ** 2 * heated_p / (rho_m * A_f) + g * rho_m) * dz
        xe_array[i] = (h_enthalpy_array[i] - hf_enthalpy) / (hg_enthalpy - hf_enthalpy)

    # Void Fraction

    if xe_array[i] <= 0:
        alpha_array[0]

    elif xe_array[i] > 0 and xe_array[i] < 1:
        x_array[i] = xe_array[i]
        vfg_sat = vg - vf
        rho_m = (vf_sat + vfg_sat * x_array) ** (-1)
        rhof = 1 / vf
        rhog = 1 / vg
        void = (rho_m - rhof) / (rhog - rhof)
        alpha_array[void]
        print("Void fraction is " + str(np.amax(alpha_array)))

    if xe_array[i] <= 0:
        alpha_array[0]
    elif xe_array[i] > 0 and xe_array[i] < 1:
        x_array[i] = xe_array[i]
        vfg_sat = vg - vf
        rho_m = (vf_sat + vfg_sat * x_array) ** (-1)
        rhof = 1 / vf
        rhog = 1 / vg
        void = (rho_m - rhof) / (rhog - rhof)
        alpha_array[void]
        print("Void fraction is " + str(np.amax(alpha_array)))

        rho_m = 1 / ((x_array[i] * vg) + ((1 - x_array[i]) * vf))
        mu_m = 1 / ((x_array[i] / mug) + ((1 - x_array[i]) / muf))

        Re[i] = (MF * D_H) / (mu_m * 10 ** 6)  # convert mu to Pa/s
        f = 0.079 * (Re[i] ** -0.25) * (mu_m / muf)
        Tau = (1 / 2) * f * ((MF ** 2) / rho_m)

        Re_f[i] = Re[i]

        vf_plus_dP = IAPWS97(P=P_array[i] + dp, x=xe_array[i]).v
        vf_minus_dP = IAPWS97(P=P_array[i] - dp, x=xe_array[i]).v

        ddP_vf = (vf_plus_dP - vf_minus_dP) / (2 * (dp * 10 ** 6))

        frictional[i] = (Tau * wetted_p) / A_f
        gravitational[i] = g * rho_f
        compressibility[i] = (MF ** 2) * (ddP_vf)

        dPdz_num = (frictional[i] + gravitational[i])  # Pa/m
        dPdz_denom = 1 + compressibility[i]  # Pa/m
        dPdz = -dPdz_num / dPdz_denom  # Pa/m

        P_array[i + 1] = P_array[i] + ((dPdz * dz) * 10 ** (-6))
        T_f_array[i + 1] = IAPWS97(P=P_array[i + 1], h=h_enthalpy_array[i + 1]).T
        T_sat[i + 1] = IAPWS97(P=P_array[i + 1], x=0).T

    # final calc for final value of quality and void fraction because loop stops before these
    hf_final = IAPWS97(P=P_array[-1], x=0).h
    hg_final = IAPWS97(P=P_array[-1], x=1).h
    muf_final = (IAPWS97(P=P_array[-1], x=0).mu) * 10 ** (-6)
    mug_final = (IAPWS97(P=P_array[-1], x=1).mu) * 10 ** (-6)
    k_fluid[-1] = IAPWS97(P=P_array[-1], T=T_f_array[-1]).k

    xe_array[-1] = (h_enthalpy_array[-1] - hf_final) / (hg_final - hf_final)

    # fuel and clad temps
    T_C_Outer = np.zeros(len(z_array))

    mu_m_final = 1 / ((x_array[-1] / mug_final) + ((1 - x_array[-1]) / muf_final))

    Re_f[-1] = (MF * D_H) / (muf_final * 10 ** 6)

    Pr[-1] = IAPWS97(P=P_array[i], h=h_enthalpy_array[i]).Liquid.Prandt

    h_HT = 0.023 * (Re_f[0] ** 0.8) * (Pr[0] ** 0.4) * (k_fluid[0] / D_H)

    T_C_Outer[0] = (q_heat_flux[0] + (h_HT * T_f_array[0])) / h_HT

    for i in range(0, len(z_array) - 1):
        h_HT = 0.023 * (Re_f[i + 1] ** 0.8) * (Pr[i + 1] ** 0.4) * (k_fluid[i + 1] / D_H)
        T_C_Outer[i + 1] = (q_heat_flux[i + 1] + (h_HT * T_f_array[i + 1])) / h_HT

    q_triple_prime = (q_prime * 4) / (np.pi * (D_fuel ** 2))

    T_C_Inner = np.zeros(len(z_array))
    T_F_Outer = np.zeros(len(z_array))
    T_F_Center = np.zeros(len(z_array))

    for i in range(0, len(z_array)):
        C1 = -((q0_prime * R_clad) / (k_c * heated_p)) * np.sin(np.pi * (z_array[i] / H))
        C2 = T_C_Outer[i] - (C1 * np.log(R_clad))

        T_C_Inner[i] = (C1 * np.log(R_gap)) + C2

        C3 = (k_c / k_gap) * C1
        C4 = T_C_Inner[i] - (C3 * np.log(R_gap))

        T_F_Outer[i] = (C3 * np.log(R_fuel)) + C4

        C6 = T_F_Outer[i] + ((q_triple_prime[i] * (R_fuel ** 2)) / (4 * k_fuel))

        T_F_Center[i] = C6

    CL_max = np.amax(T_F_Center)
    index = np.where(T_F_Center == CL_max)
    z_CL_max = z_array[index]

    plt.figure(1)
    plt.plot(T_C_Outer, z_arrayplots, label='Clad Outer Surface Temp')
    plt.plot(T_C_Inner, z_arrayplots, label='Clad Inner Surface Temp')
    plt.legend(loc='upper left')
    plt.xlabel("Temperature [K]")
    plt.ylabel("Height z [m]")
    plt.savefig("TempCladBWR.png", dpi=600)

    plt.figure(2)
    plt.plot(T_C_Outer, z_arrayplots, label='Clad Outer Surface Temp')
    plt.plot(T_C_Inner, z_arrayplots, label='Clad Inner Surface Temp')
    plt.plot(T_F_Outer, z_arrayplots, label='Fuel Outer Surface Temp')
    plt.plot(T_F_Center, z_arrayplots, label='Fuel Centerline Temp')
    plt.legend(loc='upper left')
    plt.xlabel("Temperature [K]")
    plt.ylabel("Height z [m]")
    plt.savefig("TempFuelAndCladBWR.png", dpi=600)

    # radial calcs
    T_array_A = [T_F_Center[25], T_F_Outer[25], T_C_Inner[25], T_C_Outer[25]]
    T_array_B = [T_F_Center[49], T_F_Outer[49], T_C_Inner[49], T_C_Outer[49]]
    T_array_C = [T_F_Center[53], T_F_Outer[53], T_C_Inner[53], T_C_Outer[53]]
    r_array = [0, R_fuel, R_gap, R_clad]

    plt.figure(3)
    plt.plot(r_array, T_array_A, label='z = -H/4 = -0.9 m')
    plt.plot(r_array, T_array_B, label='z = 0 m')
    plt.plot(r_array, T_array_C, '--', label='z = zmax = 0.108 m')
    plt.legend(loc='upper left')
    plt.ylabel("Temperature [K]")
    plt.xlabel("Radius r [m]")
    plt.savefig("TempRadialBWR.png", dpi=600)

    # critical heat flux and DNBR

    P_array_DNBR = np.delete(P_array, 0)
    q_heat_flux_DNBR = np.delete(q_heat_flux, 0)
    z_arrayplots_DNBR = np.delete(z_arrayplots, 0)

    G_Mlbs = MF * (((2.20462 * 10 ** (-6)) * 3600) / 10.7639)

    q_heat_flux_MBtu = q_heat_flux[1:] * 3.41 * (1 / 1000000) * (1 / 10.7639)

    P_c = 22.064  # https://nuclearstreet.com/nuclear-power-plants/w/nuclear_power_plants/features-of-pressurized-water-reactors
    P_crit = P_array_DNBR / P_c
    P1 = 0.5328
    P2 = 0.1212
    P3 = 1.6151
    P4 = 1.4066
    P5 = -0.3040
    P6 = 0.4843
    P7 = -0.3285
    P8 = -2.0749

    A = P1 * (P_crit ** P2) * (G_Mlbs ** (P5 + (P7 * P_crit)))
    C = P3 * (P_crit ** P4) * (G_Mlbs ** (P6 + (P8 * P_crit)))

    q_crit_heat_flux_MBtu = (A - xe_array[0]) / (C + ((xe_array[1:] - xe_array[0]) / q_heat_flux_MBtu))

    q_crit_heat_flux = q_crit_heat_flux_MBtu * (1 / 3.41) * 1000000 * 10.7639

    DNBR = q_crit_heat_flux / q_heat_flux_DNBR

    plt.figure(4)
    plt.plot(DNBR, z_arrayplots_DNBR)
    plt.xlabel("Onset of Nucleate Boiling Ratio")
    plt.ylabel("Height z [m]")
    plt.title("Onset of Nucleate Boiling Ratio versus Height")
    plt.savefig("ONBR.png", dpi=600)

    plt.figure(5)
    plt.plot(P_array, z_arrayplots)
    plt.xlabel('Pressure [MPa]')
    plt.ylabel('Height z [m]')
    plt.title('Pressure versus Height')
    plt.savefig("PressureBWR.png", dpi=600)

    plt.figure(6)
    plt.plot(T_f_array, z_arrayplots)
    plt.xlabel('Temperature [K]')
    plt.ylabel('Height z [m]')
    plt.title('Coolant Temperature vs Height')
    plt.savefig("TempBulkBWR.png", dpi=600)

    plt.figure(7)
    plt.plot(T_F_Outer, z_arrayplots, label='Fuel Outer Surface Temp')
    plt.plot(T_F_Center, z_arrayplots, label='Fuel Centerline Temp')
    plt.legend(loc='upper left')
    plt.xlabel("Temperature [K]")
    plt.ylabel("Height z [m]")
    plt.savefig("TempFuelBWR.png", dpi=600)

    # density
    plt.figure(8)
    plt.plot(Density, z_arrayplots, label='Density')
    plt.legend(loc='upper left')
    plt.xlabel("Pressure [mPa]")
    plt.ylabel("Height z [m]")
    plt.savefig("Density", dpi=600)

    # quality
    plt.figure(9)
    plt.plot(x, z_arrayplots, label='Quality')
    plt.plot(xe, z_arrayplots, label='Quality')
    plt.legend(loc='upper left')
    plt.xlabel("Quality")
    plt.ylabel("Height z [m]")
    plt.savefig("Quality", dpi=600)

    # void
    plt.figure(10)
    plt.plot(alpha, z_arrayplots, label='Void Fraction')
    plt.legend(loc='upper left')
    plt.xlabel("Void Fraction")
    plt.ylabel("Height z [m]")
    plt.savefig("Void Fraction", dpi=600)

    tempdifference = T_C_Outer - T_f_array
    print("Max clad vs bulk difference is " + str(np.amax(tempdifference)) + " C")
    print("Max coolant temp is " + str(np.amax(T_f_array) - 273.15) + " C")
    print("Max coolant temp is " + str(np.amax(T_f_array)) + " K")
    print("Max clad temp is " + str(np.amax(T_C_Inner) - 273.15) + " C")
    print("Max clad temp is " + str(np.amax(T_C_Inner)) + " K")
    print("Max fuel temp is " + str(np.amax(T_F_Center) - 273.15) + " C")
    print("Max fuel temp is " + str(np.amax(T_F_Center)) + " K")
    print("Max fuel temp is " + str(np.amax(T_F_Outer) - 273.15) + " C")
    print("Max fuel temp is " + str(np.amax(T_F_Outer)) + " K")
    print("Max centerline temp occurs at z = " + str(z_CL_max) + "m")
    MDNBR = np.amin(DNBR)
    print("MDNBR is " + str(MDNBR))
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference between PWR and BWR case is that there are two phases of water (liquid and vapor) for BWR and only one for PWR (liquid).

IAPWS97 library require the users to specify which phase they want when there are several :

```
IAPWS97(T=T0, P=P0).h # if only one phase
```

Should be

```
IAPWS97(T=T0, P=P0).Liquid.h
```

or

```
IAPWS97(T=T0, P=P0).Vapor.h
```